# static initializer seems not to run during junit tests

Tags: java, android, junit, junit4

I´m unit testing a method of a static utility class:

```
@Test
public void createGenreString()
{
    //Arrange
    String expected1 = "Action, Adventure, Animation, 

    //Act
    String actual1 = Utils.createGenreString(new int[]{28, 12, 16, 35});

    //Assert
    assertThat(actual1, is(equalTo(expected1)));
}
```

This static method is accessing kind of a static map object (MovieDbContract.GENRES), of which it retrieves String values using Integer keys:

```
public static String createGenreString(int[] genreIds)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int length = genreIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length && genreIds[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0) sb.append(", ");
        String genre = MovieDbContract.GENRES.get(genreIds[i]);
        sb.append(genre != null ? genre : "Unknown");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

this static map object should be filled with data through a static initializer:

```
public static final SparseArray<String> GENRES = new SparseArray<>();

static
{
    GENRES.put(28, "Action");
    GENRES.put(12, "Adventure");
    GENRES.put(16, "Animation");
    .
    .
}
```

now the problem is that when the test runs, the map object is null, it doesn´t get filled with data, so the test fails. but the program itself works fine, with containing data. anybody an idea why during tests this is different? i´m using JUnit 4.12 and all this is done in an android environment

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: We need to see where and how the `Genres` variable is declared and assigned.

Comment: updated the declaration

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that each of your three code blocks is in a different top-level class?

Comment: yes, first is the testclass, second the utility class and third another class containing static objects with statically initialized data

Comment: what happens if you replace SparseArray with an HashMap ?

Comment: ha, with hashmap is fine. sparsearray comes from android framework...

Comment: So `GENRES` is `null`? Or are you getting `"Unknown, Unknown, ..."`?

Comment: getting Unknown, unknown.. when I debug, it shows me null for GENRE. but also a hashcode. just a bit weird everything. I think it has something to do with the android framework

Answer (score 1):

So, in this case, you needed the static map object, but in other cases where the methods you are unit testing do not need the statically initialised SparseArray, etc., another approach to avoiding doing an instrumented test and keep it as pure unit tests, is suggested in this [tools.android.com page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-), namely:

```
android {
  // ...
  testOptions { 
     unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, found out that whenever android framework classes like SparseArray or ContentValues are used in methods under test, you have to run the test as instrumented unit test (androidTest) on an emulator or device, otherwise these objects don´t get initialized like they should

Comment: I just added ```@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)``` in the test class, and it worked for me